# Bootstrap 3: What if I have an image wider than the col that wraps it?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I wonder what will happen if I have a wrapper of class "col-md-4" wrapping over an image having a larger width.

I have tested on my own browser, it seems that the image will not be limited by the col-md-4 class; that is, it will go across the column wrapper, which makes the whole page's structure hard to manipulate.

Can anyone give me any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "*image width*"?  Post your HTML.

Comment: can u show us some code ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding class="img-responsive" to the image tag and checking it?